# How to implement a gridSVG Tooltip on a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am looking for the easiest way to add a simple tooltip to a basic line chart plotted by `ggplot`.  My dataset has had some issues with `rCharts`, so I am trying to see if `gridSVG` would suit my needs.

I am building my viz in `Shiny`, and I am trying to follow the code on this `git`: https://github.com/timelyportfolio/shiny-grid-svg-v2

```
 ##ui.R##
reactiveSvg <- function (outputId) 
{
  HTML(paste("<div id=\"", outputId, "\" class=\"shiny-network-output\"><svg /></div>", sep=""))
}    

mainPanel(
              htmlOutput(outputId = "svg.grid")
               )

##server.R##
output$svg.grid <- reactiveText(function() {
    ggplot(data = sampleData, aes(x=year, y=quantity, group=sample_data))+
      geom_line()+
      ggtitle("Basic gridSVG Example")
    NOT SURE HOW TO USE GRID.SVG TO CREATE A BASIC TOOLTIP ON MY CHART
  })
```

In the above `git`, the following code is in the `server.R`.  Is this all I need?

```
print(get(exampleInput()))
    #print((paste(input$example,"example",sep=".")))
    tempsvg <- tempfile(fileext=".svg")
    on.exit(unlink(tempsvg))
    gridToSVG(name=tempsvg)
    svgoutput <- readLines(tempsvg, n=-1)
    paste(svgoutput,sep="")
```

Comment: have you seen http://htmlwidgets.org?  This might be much easier than the `gridSVG` method.